# Does a Rune Knight fighter using the Giant's Might feature get a bonus to their weapon's damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, creature-size, oversized-weapons, rune-knight

The description of the Giant's Might feature for the Rune Knight fighter in *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* (p. 45) says that their weapons and armor grow with them, meaning their sword would be large/oversized.

Giant weapons roll double the dice. Would a Rune Knight fighter using the Giant's Might feature benefit from this?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: The players handbook says that oversized weapons deal an extra dice roll. For instance a weapon that would roll 1d8 would roll 2d8 if it is oversized. Giants use oversized weapons, and when using giants might the book says that you along with everything you are wearing grows to large size. I am wondering if that would mean your weapon is oversized.

Comment: Are you referring to the following quote from DMG p. 278 (not the PHB), under ["Step 11. Damage"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#Step11Damage) of the "Creating a Monster Statblock" section: "Big monsters typically wield oversized weapons that deal extra dice of damage on a hit. Double the weapon dice if the creature is Large, triple the weapon dice if it’s Huge, and quadruple the weapon dice if it’s Gargantuan. For example, a Huge giant wielding an appropriately sized greataxe deals 3d12 slashing damage (plus its Strength bonus), instead of the normal 1d12."?

Comment: Yeah that is the passage in question.

Answer (score 11):

#### The class feature description has everything you need to know.

The feature description for Giant’s Might is complete - you don’t have to look elsewhere to learn its effects:

> As a bonus action, *you magically gain the following benefits*, which last for 1 minute:
>
> - If you are smaller than Large, you become Large, along with anything you are wearing. If you lack the room to become Large, your size doesn’t change.
> - You have advantage on Strength checks and Strength saving throws.
> - *Once on each of your turns, one of your attacks with a weapon or an unarmed strike can deal an extra 1d6 damage to a target on a hit.*

A little bit of extra damage is baked into the feature, and these are all the benefits of the feature. You don’t have to look elsewhere to learn how this feature works.

#### You don't need the *Monster Manual* or *Dungeon Master's Guide* to understand your class features.

The *Dungeon Master's Guide* contains guidance for the DM can use to create new monster stat blocks:

> If you want a full monster stat block, use the following method to create your new monster.
>
> The introduction to the Monster Manual explains all the components of a monster’s stat block. Familiarize yourself with that material before you begin. In the course of creating your monster, if you find yourself unable to make a decision, let the examples in the Monster Manual guide you.
>
> Once you have a monster concept in mind, follow the steps below.

The instructions for creating a monster include the following guidance for bigger monsters, which is where you got the idea:

> Big monsters typically wield oversized weapons that deal extra dice of damage on a hit. Double the weapon dice if the creature is Large, triple the weapon dice if it’s Huge, and quadruple the weapon dice if it’s Gargantuan. For example, a Huge giant wielding an appropriately sized greataxe deals 3d12 slashing damage (plus its Strength bonus), instead of the normal 1d12.

This is guidance for the DM to use to homebrew a monster. *This has nothing to do with player character class features*. This section isn't even giving "rules" about anything. This is telling the DM, "If you want to create a monster, here's some help".

Comment: Thank you for the response, I appreciate it. My thinking in this however is that if I found a giant sword naturally, it would take on its properties of an oversized sword. Using giants might, my sword would be the same size as the giant one that I found but wouldn't do the same damage. I figured the page mentioning the size change for your weapons and armor would insinuate they behave slightly different now.

Comment: @ThomasOuellette I added a section addressing the DMG stuff.

Comment: So if they pick a monstrous race, how do you squirm out of that? And if they pick up a monster's large size weapon, do you still deny them the higher damage? "because you aren't a monster" is one of the biggest cheats I have seen in this game.

Comment: Humans, elves, dwarves and others are in the Monster Manual, so they do qualify as monsters by your weird logic.

Comment: @Grond There is a difference between PC rules and monster/NPC rules. "Monstrous race" PCs are still PCs, so use PC rules. And although NPCs may not be "monstrous", they're listed in the Monster Manual, and use the same rules as monsters.

Comment: @Grond I’m not sure what you’re talking about, sorry. I’m not aware of “monstrous races” that have different rules from other playable races.

Comment: @Grond I think you are incorrectly interpreting Thomas' argument as "the monsters with oversize weapons get extra damage dice _because they are monsters_". What is actually being stated is that the rules cited are not about properties of oversized weapons at all, but about _creating homebrew monster statblocks_.

Comment: The properties you are taking as "rules for oversized weapons" aren't even always followed in the _Monster Manual_ statblocks. For example (all from _MM_): Centaur, Drider, and Lamia are large creatures that use weapons that only deal one damage die. In [another answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/198761/63795) Thomas gives the example of Baphomet, who is huge but whose glaive only deals two damage dice.

Comment: So, if they pick up an actual large size weapon, do you still screw the player out of the oversized weapon damage when they use it? (As opposed to when it was used on them with that damage)

Comment: @Grond If player characters were meant to have and use oversized weapons with upscaled damage, those weapons would appear in the weapons section of the ***Player's** Handbook*. If tripling your damage were as simple as going to the smith and saying "I'd like one XXXL sword please", why are magic weapons that do much less damage so expensive? There are numerous game balance and narrative balance issues that arise from allowing the PCs to use oversized weapons with increased damage.

Comment: Your comment's logic is greatly flawed and ridiculous. You assume every player can assume this Giant Might form, as this is the only on who can wield such weapons. **A large-sized shortsword is already in the PHB, it is called the Greatsword**. But to wield it you need two hands. A large size Greatsword cannot be wielded by a medium sized creature in this version of the game, so NOBODY, except this specific subclass can use it, and it would be a waste of money to say "I'd like one XXXL sword please". This is an inane response to a logical situation for a specific subclass.

Comment: @Grond Sure, if you pick up a giant shortsword and wield it with two hands I'll let it do 2d6 damage instead of 1d6.

Answer (score -4):

It doesn't say that the items change in size, sadly. It only specifies what is being worn.

I would agree that if it did change the weapon to an oversized weapon, it should gain the extra damage dice.

A "monster" is specified as such, if you wanna use the DMG and Monster Manual for such a ruling. The definition is located in the Introduction of the Monster Manual.

> A monster is defined as any creature that can be interacted with and potentially fought and killed. Even something as harmless as a frog or as benevolent as a unicorn is a monster by this definition. The term also applies to humans, elves, dwarves, and other civilized folk who might be friends or rivals to the player characters. Most of the monsters that haunt the D&D world, however, are threats that are meant to be stopped: rampaging demons, conniving devils, soul-sucking undead, summoned elementals — the list goes on.

Therefore, player characters also qualify as "monsters".

It's really up to the GM if the weapon size increased via the feature, but the only other plausible way to get that extra d12 on your Battleaxe is if someone used Enlarge/Reduce.

Answer (score -6):

Here is one of the great things about being a DM. You can chose to be fair and make your own ruling on these types of things. You can spend your game trying to come up with excuses to cheat players.

The feature does what it says. Since the Giant Might ability clearly says "you become large, along with anything you are wearing." Anything you are wearing, this includes carrying, is now a size larger, *and we now need to know if this change affects the weapon in some way, Thus, we now need to know what a large size, or over-sized weapon does for damage*. The **Dungeon Masters Guide has rules for oversized weapons on pages 277-278**. It begins by talking about monsters who have oversized weapons and how to calculate for oversized weapons. This should definitely include your currently over-sized (large) weapons, making them one level of over-sized, which by RAW (Rules As Written) doubles their dice.

**If your DM makes it all about "oversized weapons only apply to monsters", then do what a guy in the campaign I am playing in did, and chose a "monstrous" race** like the Bugbear, Centaur, Deep Gnome, Duergar, Fairy, Firbolg, Githyanki, Githzerai, Goblin, Grung, Hobgoblin, Kobold, Lizardfolk, Merfolk, Minotaur, Naga, Orc, Satyr, Siren, Vampire or Yuan-Ti. All of these are races from the Monster Manual, so all of these would qualify, even by the DM’s twisted interpretation of RAW. In this example, the player literally has a Minotaur with a greataxe.

There is no way you can tell me that when a Large size Minotaur with an vicious, large-sized, two handed Greataxe charges to attack you, that it isn't going to cause massively more damage than usual. Any other answer than "yes" and I call, "BS" !

**Finally, the best solution to this mess that gives you large-size weapon damage that is impossible to ignore. Take Smith Tools, or hire a Smith, and make a large weapon. You can also get large weapons for free off dead creatures of large size (bugbear, minotaur, Fiends, golems, etc.).** *Carry the weapon with you, pull it out, put it on the ground and lean it against your body/leg. When you grow, grab the large weapon that already has the increased damage and use it.* **Now there is no way, without being the world's greatest hypocrite and cheat, the DM will HAVE to give you the appropriate damage.**

*You can even then ask, after that combat, what is the difference between the large weapon you brought, and the large weapon you also hold, that grew with you. At this point it is fun to watch people dancing to justify their contrary logic/ruling.*

Comment: To give some feedback on my downvote, the section of the DMG you mention from pp. 277-278 *is guidance for homebrewing creatures, not rules for the players to use*. I discuss this briefly in my own answer to this question, and in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/198761/62294) I give a more thorough presentation of the context of that section. It's guidance for creating a monster, not rules players can point to and say "but RAW...".

Comment: "The Dungeon Masters Guide has rules for oversized weapons on pages 277-278."  No it doesn't - it provides guidance for DMs on how much damage they might want to have larger-than-medium enemies deal if they're creating their own.  This is not a rule, and besides is arguably a "class feature" of that specific monster rather than a property of the weapon-object.

Comment: If I could downvote this twice, I would, since it gives terrible advice for handling disagreements at the table.

Comment: The DMG pages ARE a way to calculate over-sized weapons. I see someone changed their erroneous answer that said only in the MM. You can chose to ignore it, you can chose to ignore a monstrous race, which another DM didn't. You can go out of your way to make sure they never get their hands on an over-sized weapon from a smith or a dead opponent. It must be exhausting, working so hard to avoid the inevitable.

Comment: 5e *is not* 3.5e. PC race Minotaur is a totally different thing to the MM entry Minotaur. The former is a Medium Humanoid, the latter is a Large Monstrosity. "Guard *Medium Humanoid  (Any Race)*" uses monster rules, is present in the monster manual, is a monster *to the rules*