# Do you get the benefits of Oversized Weapons with Path of Giant?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, barbarian, archetype, oversized-weapons

The description of the Path of the Giant barbarian's Elemental Cleaver feature (from Bigby Presents: Glory of the Giants) says, in part:

> Giant Stature: Your reach increases by 5 feet, and if you are smaller than Large, **you become Large, along with anything you are wearing.**

So here's my question: could this feature work with the Oversized Weapon rule showcased on page 278 of the DMG? I know that this rule is mostly here to provide guidelines for DMs when crafting their own monster statblocks, but it seems that most Large and bigger creatures use these rules for their weapon attacks anyway. What do you guys think?

Comment: Related, [among others](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/208384/do-you-get-the-benefits-of-oversized-weapons-with-path-of-giant#comment572014_208385): [Are Goliaths able to wield large-sized weapons?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/58816/23547)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### The class feature description has everything you need to know.

The feature description for Giant Stature is complete - you don’t have to look elsewhere to learn its effects:

> While raging, you gain the following benefits:
>
> [...]
>
> **Giant Stature.** Your reach increases by 5 feet, and if you are smaller than Large, you become Large, along with anything you are wearing. If there isn’t enough room for you to increase your size, your size doesn’t change.

This is everything you need to know to play this character using this feature. You don’t have to look elsewhere to learn how this feature works. Thus, you get no extra damage, you don’t gain the ability to wield large weapons, since extra damage and large weapons are not listed as one of "the following benefits".

#### You don't need the *Monster Manual* or *Dungeon Master's Guide* to understand your class features.

The *Dungeon Master's Guide* contains guidance for the DM can use to create new monster stat blocks:

> If you want a full monster stat block, use the following method to create your new monster.
>
> The introduction to the Monster Manual explains all the components of a monster’s stat block. Familiarize yourself with that material before you begin. In the course of creating your monster, if you find yourself unable to make a decision, let the examples in the Monster Manual guide you.
>
> Once you have a monster concept in mind, follow the steps below.

The instructions for creating a monster include the following guidance for bigger monsters, which is where the notion of oversized weapons comes from:

> Big monsters typically wield oversized weapons that deal extra dice of damage on a hit. Double the weapon dice if the creature is Large, triple the weapon dice if it’s Huge, and quadruple the weapon dice if it’s Gargantuan. For example, a Huge giant wielding an appropriately sized greataxe deals 3d12 slashing damage (plus its Strength bonus), instead of the normal 1d12.

This is guidance for the DM to use to homebrew a monster. *This has nothing to do with player character class features*. This section isn't even giving "rules" about anything. This is telling the DM, "If you want to create a monster, here's some help".

For more in-depth commentary on the so called "oversized weapons rule", see [my answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/198761/62294) to the question, [How does the Enlarge/Reduce spell interact with the Oversized Weapons rule when you Enlarge a Medium size creature with a medium weapon to Large size?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/198758/62294).

---

Answer adapted from [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/183428/62294) to the same question about a different class's feature.

Comment: +1 If there is one perennial expert on this thing about using large weapons with PCs, it's certainly you.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin Yeah, I've answered different versions of this question several times.

Comment: So there is no way to gain the damage boost from an Oversized Weapon as a PC in D&D? Not even by looting it from a creature or by making one yourself?

Comment: @Duhl No, because the oversized weapon rule isn't actually a rule. It is a design principle given as guidance for the DM to build custom monsters. The closest thing to this is the legendary magic item Gurt's Greataxe, which deals 3d12 on a hit or 5d12 if the target is human. *But it is a legendary item*, and its item description explicitly states what its damage is.

Comment: And a good thing, too; it would be deeply unbalanced if players could access it.

Answer (score -2):

So here is the deal with this. If you find a weapon on a large or huge creature. That weapon is the thing that deals more damage as it is heavier and more durable since it is so large. If you take the weapon from a large or huge creature, the damage dice still applies. Because the damage is from the large weapon the creature is wielding not the creature itself.

The strength modifier determines how much stronger the creature is, but the weapon HAS to be appropriate sized for that creature. So by RAW you picking up that blade, then raging to become a large/huge creature when using it, you could use it as normal. But your base weapon grows with  you, but is not made to sustain that form. That's why it maintains the weaker damage.

Edit: People down voting this don't understand strength modifiers and basic physics. If I take a pebble and hand it to a child to throw their damage would be 1d4+1 for example. An adult throwing that same pebble would be 1d4+5. As their strength is much greater. Same applies to weapons. If I give a rock the size of a basketball to the child, he could not wield it. But the adult could through it for 3d4+5 damage. As per the rules on oversized weapons.

If you loot a shortbow off a goblins dead body and they only have a +1 to their modifiers. And your rogue picks up the bow and has a +4 modifier. What changes? The dice damage of the arrow? Or just the modifier?

So grabbing a giant sword off of a giant who swings that sword for 3d10+7 damage given to a path of the giant barbarian, at the levels they can become huge, would deal 3d10+5(at 20 str). The weapon damage only changes based on strength modifiers.

How many times do DMs let their players loot long swords, shields and crossbows off enemies? All those stats from the bandits or goblins or whoever are NEVER altered. So why would you alter the stats of big weapons that on the rare case playing a niche subclass, that could actually be used? Only if you wish to not follow RAW and make a ruling for that table. Otherwise totally viable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).